# How do I allocate more memory to an app on Sheepshaver running Mac OS 9?

Tags: memory, mac-os-classic, sheepshaver

I'm trying to play Taskmaker on Mac OS 9 in Sheepshaver on OSX. Taskmaker tells me that it doesn't have enough memory to run in color. Within technical support it says that I have 512 megabytes total memory, 2295K approximate partition, 1676K available. I've tried bumping the RAM up and down, and while I have many megabytes to spare, I can't seem to get more "available" to Taskmaker.

Any suggestions welcome... is there some setting in OS9 that I need to set? I've gone to the memory control panel and tried messing with RAM Disk and Disk Cache, to no avail.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Click on the application icon, select "Get info" from the "File" menu, and adjust the memory allocation in the window that pops up.

Answer (score 5):

Many older Mac games were written to work best in 256-color (8-bit color) modes. Your system is probably set to use thousands or millions of colors (16- or 32-bit color); these modes do not improve the appearance of these games, and may make them slower or -- in Taskmaker's case -- may even prevent them from launching normally.

Change the display depth of your emulated system to 256 colors. If you're running a default install of Mac OS 9, you can do this by opening the Control Strip and clicking on the icon that looks like a TV with blue, yellow, red, and green bars on it. You can also change this in the Monitors control panel.